# InfoPath SaveAs functionality

Tags: infopath

Can the save as file name be entered automatically into the save dialog(from a field in the form) so it doesn’t have to be entered by the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Sumit data connection. While creating the connection mention the name of the file (this could be from a control in the form)

Programmatically submit the data using the following code:

DataConnection spConn = DataConnections["Sharepoint Library Submit"];
 spConn.Execute();